# What to use instead of startActivity(intent) in FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onclicklistener, android-fragmentactivity

For some reason in FragmentActivity, startActivity() doesn't work, it crashes the app when I click on my button and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.name.app/com.example.name.app.WorldTabBar}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.name.app.WorldTabBar cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Here's my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

Button live;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


live=findViewById((R.id.GoToLive));

live.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent startIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, WorldTabBar.class);
              startActivity(startIntent);                  
        }
    });
```

startActivity() crashes the app in FragmentActivity. FragmentActivity doesn't allow me to use getActivity() because I'm just supposed to use ".this" but that doesn't work with startActivity().

I tried instead of FragmentActivity, to use just extends Fragment and changed onCreate to onCreateView method with rootView then added getActivity() everywhere and

```
getActivity().startActivity(startIntent);  //<-didn't work, crashes again
```

Here's, my manifest.xml:

```
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
   <activity android:name=".WorldTabBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/myKey" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
</application>
```

Maybe there's something I can use instead of startActivity() yet it does the same action? In fact...

```
   Intent startIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, WorldTabBar.class);
```

...^ the above code works by itself without startActivity() even but then i think without a start code, now my overridePendingTransition code doesn't get recognized. So is there some code I can use in FragmentActivity that works like startActivity() but isn't startActivity()?

EDIT:

WorldTabBar class:

```
   public class WorldTabBar extends Fragment {


    Button world;

   @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_world_tabbar, container, false);




    world=rootView.findViewById(R.id.GoToWorld);
            world.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                     Intent startIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                     startActivity(startIntent);

     getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.no_anim);

                     }
            });

    return rootView;
    }


    }
```

Comment: could you please add the code for `WorldTabBar` - which class does it extend?

Comment: I added WorldTabBar class in code.

Comment: If you want to start fragment from an activity class then check out this link: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/starting-a-fragment-from-an-activity. it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.name.app.WorldTabBar cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Your `WorldTabBar` extends `Fragment`, not `Activity` class.

1) You need to add the activity, then add `WorldTabBar` fragment to it.

For example, create `WorldTabBarActivity` extends `Activity`, register it on manifest on use this activity with intent:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, WorldTabBarActivity.class);
```

One of the options to add the fragment to activity (using XML) described here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html. Another option - add fragment at runtime - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime

2) Change the code to make it activity:

```
public class WorldTabBar extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: What am I supposed to change then?